# Multiple select and v-model with array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue.js 2.0 and the Element UI library.

I'm working with a **multiple select component**. 
The v-model property is here to pre-select any options.
So if you have `model: ['Option4']`, the select will be preselected with Option4

I would like to be able to `v-model` an array of object instead of simply an array containing the label of each option.

That is to say instead of using`model: ['Option4']` I would like to be able to use something like `model: [{name:'Option4'}, {name:'Option5'}]`.

When doing so the pre-selection is not made properly.

Is it possible to do that ? If so how ?

http://jsfiddle.net/3ra1jscx/

```
<div id="app">
<template>
  <el-select v-model="model" multiple placeholder="Select">
    <el-option v-for="item in options" :label="item.label" :value="item.value">
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
</template>
</div>

var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        options: [{
          value: 1,
          label: 'Option1'
        }, {
          value: 2,
          label: 'Option2'
        }, {
          value: 3,
          label: 'Option3'
        }, {
          value: 4,
          label: 'Option4'
        }, {
          value: 5,
          label: 'Option5'
        }],
        model: ['Option4']
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Comment: why do you remove `accepted answer` from my answer ?

Comment: Hello Alexandru, I followed your advice and now I'm putting it into context. The preselection is ok but I can't select another option. Any idea ?

Comment: I don't understant why you can't select another option.In edited fiddle it is working perfectly.Have a look.

Comment: I'm going to create a new task for that. I'm sorry. Yes this one is working perfectly but the issue I posted here does not illustrate the whole story. Maybe you will be able to help me on the next one I'm going to create.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241149/multiple-select-vue-js-and-computed-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the `value` of object in `options` array.

```
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      options: [{
        value: 1,
        label: 'Option1'
      }, {
        value: 2,
        label: 'Option2'
      }, {
        value: 3,
        label: 'Option3'
      }, {
        value: 4,
        label: 'Option4'
      }, {
        value: 5,
        label: 'Option5'
      }],
      model: [4]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is [working solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/3ra1jscx/1/)