# Multiple select Vue.js and computed property

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm using Vue.js 2.0 and the Element UI library.

I want to use a multiple select to attribute some roles to my users.

The list of all roles available is received and assigned to `availableRoles`. Since it is an array of object and the `v-model` accepts only an array with value, I need to extract the `id` of the roles trough the computed property `computedRoles`.

The current roles of my user are received and assigned to `userRoles: [{'id':1, 'name':'Admin'}, {'id':3, 'name':'User'}]`.

`computedRoles` is then equals to `[1,3]`

The preselection of the select is fine but I can't change anything (add or remove option from the select)

What is wrong and how to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/3ra1jscx/3/

```
<div id="app">
    <template>
      <el-select v-model="computedRoles" multiple placeholder="Select">
        <el-option v-for="item in availableRoles" :label="item.name" :value="item.id">
        </el-option>
      </el-select>
    </template>
</div>

var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        availableRoles: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Admin'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Power User'
        }, {
          id: 3,
          name: 'User'
        }],
        userRoles: [{'id':1, 'name':'Admin'}, {'id':3, 'name':'User'}]
      }
    },

    computed : {

        computedRoles () {
            return this.userRoles.map(role => role.id)
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree mostly with @wostex answer, but he doesn't give you the `userRoles` property back. Essentially you should swap `computedRoles` and `userRoles`. `userRoles` becomes a computed property and `computedRoles` is a data property. In my update, I changed the name of `computedRoles` to `selectedRoles`.

```
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        availableRoles: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Admin'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Power User'
        }, {
          id: 3,
          name: 'User'
        }],
        selectedRoles:[1,2]
      }
    },
    computed : {
      userRoles(){
         return this.availableRoles.reduce((selected, role) => {
             if (this.selectedRoles.includes(role.id))
                    selected.push(role);
             return selected;
         }, [])
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ra1jscx/5/).

Answer (score 1):

Check the solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3h3da4wa/1/)

The caveat here is that computed properties are getters mainly. You can define setter for computed property, but my approach is more vue-like in my opinion.

In short, instead of `v-model` on computed set `v-model` for data property.

Full code:

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
  <el-select v-model="ids" multiple placeholder="Select" @change="logit()">
    <el-option v-for="item in availableRoles" :label="item.name" :value="item.id">
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
</template>
</div>

var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        availableRoles: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Admin'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Power User'
        }, {
          id: 3,
          name: 'User'
        }],
        userRoles: [{'id':1, 'name':'Admin'}, {'id':3, 'name':'User'}],
        ids: []
      }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.ids = this.userRoles.map(role => role.id);
    },
    methods: {
        logit: function() {
        console.log(this.ids);
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```